# Setting an object from .NET to JavaScript code through WebView2

Tags: .net, webview, webbrowser-control, chromium, webview2

Thanks in advance,

I want to set an object to the java script code which is contained within a WebPage. I am displaying this Web page in the WPF window that references the WebView2 with Name as 'webView'.

I am pretty new to WebView2 and I am not absolutely sure how to pass 'name' and 'object' in AddHostObjectToScript() method of WebView2 SDK

Here is what I have tried:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ObjectHandle
{

  public Products(IPriceService priceDetails,IBillService billDetails)
  {  
     PriceDetails = priceDetails;
     BillDetails = billDetails;
  }

  public IPriceService PriceDetails { get; private set; }

  public IBillService  BillDetails { get; private set; }

}

public class WebViewBrowser:Window
{
   public WebViewBrowser()
   {
     InitializeComponent();
     InitializeAsync();
   }

   private void SetScriptingObject
   {
      ObjectHandle objHandle = new ObjectHandle(priceDetails,billDetails);
               
      webView.corewebview2.AddHostObjectToScript("ObjectHandle",objHandle );                                                                            
   }

   async void InitializeAsync()
   {
      await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question! We plan to update our C# sample apps to show how to use AddHostObjectToScript as it is not obvious.

Classes that you intend to use with AddHostObjectToScript need to be marked with the following attributes:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Example
{

    // Sample property.
    public string Prop { get; set; } = "example";
}
```

Then later you call AddHostObjectToScript like you're already doing above with an instance of your class and the name set to whatever you want to call your object from script.

```
webView.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("example", new Example());
```

Then in script you can use that object via `chrome.webview.hostObjects.{name of host object}`:

```
const example = chrome.webview.hostObjects.example;
const value = await example.Prop;
```

For now see the [C++ WebView2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/0-9-538/icorewebview2#addhostobjecttoscript) and [sample code](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/search?q=addhostobjecttoscript&unscoped_q=addhostobjecttoscript) for how to use projected host objects in script. We should add better .NET documentation for this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @David Risney. I could pass the COM object to JavaScript using above approach !

Comment: I tried this method
`const example = chrome.webview.hostObjects.example;` It works for a while, but then stops working. A theory says it has to to with JavaScript garbage collection, but I found that if I use `const value = await chrome.webview.hostObjects.example.Prop` directly, instead of `const value = await example.Prop;` then there is no problem.