# How to receive JavaScript object in C# when using Webview2 without using JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, interop, webview2

I am playing with Webview2 and tried to pass JavaScript object to C# method of registered Host Object, but I do not know how to retrieve its content.

```
public object[] TestCall(string arg1, object arg2)
{
    // arg2.item1 // This don't work
    // Including arg2 in array will return it back to JavaScript, so it is stored some where
    return new List<object>() { "item1", "item2", 123, false, arg1, arg2 }.ToArray();
}
// await window.chrome.webview.hostObjects.dotNetObject.TestCall("Hello world", { item1: "value1", item2: 1234 });
```

I tried to look up official C# samples, but none demonstrated how to pass JavaScript object into method of HostObject.

I had worked around this by using JSON to exchange data between C# and JavaScript.

Yet I'm still puzzled.

**My question:**

How do I pass any JavaScript object into method of HostObject without stringify it to JSON?

Is there anyway to get content out of JS object I received in `arg2`?

**What I tried**

- I used `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(arg2);` to get a pointer.

  But I do not know what to do with it, since I do not have knowledge of COM or IDispatch.
- I tried casting it to `ExpandoObject`, `Invalid cast`
- I tried casting it to `dynamic`, successful, but `((dynamic)arg2).item1` throws `NotImplementedException`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting an object from .NET to JavaScript code through WebView2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794609/setting-an-object-from-net-to-javascript-code-through-webview2)

Comment: Here's another example: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addhostobjecttoscript?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1108.44#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2-addhostobjecttoscript(system-string-system-object)

Comment: No. I am not trying to `addHostObjectToScript()`. I already did that. I have added a host object with a method `TestCall`. I am trying to pass JavaScript object to it like this `hostobj.TestCall(1234, { item1: 1111, item2: 2222 });`. My problem is I cannot get the data in supplied JavaScript object in C#

Comment: Try this: `public dynamic[] TestCall(string arg1, dynamic arg2)` (the `object` type does not have those proerties).

Comment: Or (better), create a class with those properties.

Comment: `'arg2.num' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException'`. Result is same as casting object to dynamic

Comment: `arg2.num` is not part of the object you send.

Comment: Sorry, I use different variable names. However, it makes no difference, still end up with NotImplementedException. `arg2.item1' threw an exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException`

Comment: Under the section 'Passing Objects to .NET' under https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2021/Jan/26/Chromium-WebView2-Control-and-NET-to-JavaScript-Interop-Part-2 , the article suggests this isn't possible. But, obviously, both the article and this question are dated.

Comment: @ianmac45 I used JSON as work around, as long as it is not performance critical, it will work fine.